# How can I identify GPS sattelites in TinyGPS++?

Tags: gps, tinygps

I can see about 15 satellites (about 10 GPS + 5 Glonass) in u-center, but I see only about 10 satellites using TinyGPS++. I suspect that TinyGPS++ can see GPS only. I see lines containing $GNRMC $GNVTG $GNGGA $GPGSV $GNGLL $GNVTG $GLGSV in the input, so there are information from both constellation. But how can I check which constellations TinyGPS++ takes into account for the output:

> Sats=10 Nums=1 3 8 10 11 14 20 22 24 27 28 31 32 36 40  Elevation=46
>   17 45 31 69 59 1 43 5 24 9 1 60 36 32  Azimuth=304 255 215 66 267 137
>   77 263 28 184 316 140 89 181 150  SNR=12 0 0 17 8 20 0 11 0 11 0 0 21
>   0 0

Comment: TinyGPS++ is just a text parsing library you can read and examine

Comment: https://www.gpsinformation.org/dale/nmea.htm#GSV SNR=0 means the satellite can be seen but may not be being used for your positional fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bug in TinyGPS++ as it only counts GPS satellites. See https://github.com/mikalhart/TinyGPSPlus/issues/52

PRN numbers are used to identify satellites:

> GPS = 1 to 32
>
> SBAS = 33 to 64 (add 87 for PRN number)
>
> GLO = 65 to 96